# Category Values parameter for v.net.steiner

Tags: grass-gis, error, network

So I need to extract the steiner tree along a line network connecting a set of points. The one part I don't quite get is what to add for the required **Category values** parameter.

[image: v.net.steiner]

I initially thought that it was the range of category values for the nodes so I entered 1 - 340. However I received the following error when I tried to run the algorithm:

```
Number of terminals: 0
ERROR: Not enough terminals (< 2)
```

I'm quite new to using GIS and GRASS in particular. Any help would be great.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm facing the same problem.